# Q. Chrome Remote Desktop showing transparent windows

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-remote-desktop

When accessing my remote PC through Chrome Remote Desktop from either 1) another Windows PC or 2) Android app, most application windows have been completely transparent (Example: Origin and AMD software windows in the screenshot). Is there a way to resolve this?

[image: Desktop Screenshot]

Comment: Try to disable hardware acceleration on Chrome: Enter `chrome://settings`, Advanced, System, uncheck "Use hardware acceleration when available".

Comment: call chrome with the `--disable-gpu` option. Is the same as @harrymc suggests, only not permanent.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the suggestions, I've tried disabling hardware acceleration on both the remote and host pcs but am having no luck seeing the content inside the window.

Comment: @rsiya does the target computer have its lid open or closed?